# How to wrap css/js in webjar?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, webjars

I want to create webjar of my own project so that i can use them same as other jar files in project . I search on google but couldn't find way to create my own webjar and publish it to repository .

Link i found which is useful but not detailed that i can use it is : http://www.appsdev.is.ed.ac.uk/blog/?p=693 .
If someone can tell where to look for this task or how can i create it will be very helpful .

Answer (score 1):

You can find more info on creating a WebJar from scratch at: http://www.webjars.org/contributing

Comment: that page is broken as the example isn't rendering

Comment: chrome no pom.xml

Comment: Oh, that is loading from GitHub and I bet that you are hitting API limits.  I need better error handling.  In the meantime you can get the content at: https://github.com/webjars/webjars-template-zip/blob/master/pom.xml